# How to random swap CFG grammar?

Tags: python

I want to randomly swap the grammar I defined for CFG. For example I have this grammar:

```
      grammar = CFG.fromstring(f"""
          S ->  NP VP | VP NP
          NP -> DET N| ADJ N 
          VP -> V NP | V ADJ | V ADV
          V -> {VERB}
          N -> {NOUN}
          ADJ ->{ADJ}
          DET -> {DET}
          ADV -> {ADV}
   
         """)
```

I want to randomly swap **S -> NP VP | VP NP** to **S -> VP NP | NP VP** in each iteration and in each iteration I'll be generate only one sentence.

```
import spacy
import codecs
import nltk
from nltk.parse.generate import generate,demo_grammar
import random
from nltk import Nonterminal
import substitute
from nltk.grammar import CFG

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
  

fin = [
       "Wow!The movie was a complete joy to watch, with an incredible cast delivering fantastic performances. The special effects were stunning. I highly recommend this movie to everyone."
       ]  

for line in fin:
    sent = line #Stripping the dataset based on tab. That is stripping label from sentence

    words = [x.lower() for x in nltk.word_tokenize(sent)] #lowering the sentence and tokenizing
    sent =  ' '.join(words)
    text = sent
    doc = nlp(text)


    noun = []
    verb = []
    adj =  []
    det =  []
    adv =  []
    pq = []
    pp = []
    intj = []
    part = []
        
    not_or_no = ""
      # Token and Tag
    for token in doc:

      if token.text=="not" or token.text=="no":
        print("found")
        not_or_no = token.text
        continue

      # print(token.pos_)
      if token.pos_ == "NOUN" or token.pos_ == "PROPN" or token.pos_ == "PRON":
        noun.append(not_or_no + " " + token.text)
      elif token.pos_ == "VERB" or token.pos_ == "AUX":
        verb.append(not_or_no + " " + token.text)
      elif token.pos_ == "DET":
        det.append(token)
      elif token.pos_ == "ADJ":
        adj.append(not_or_no + " " + token.text)
      elif token.pos_ == "ADV":
        adv.append(not_or_no + " " + token.text)
      
      not_or_no = ""

      NOUN = ''
      VERB = ' '
      DET = ''
      ADV = ''
      ADJ = ' '
      CONJ = ''
      ADP = ''

      
      for i in range(0,len(noun)):
          NOUN +=  '"' + str(noun[i]) + '"'
          if i != len(noun)-1 and len(noun) != 1:
              NOUN += ' | '

      for i in range(0,len(verb)):
          VERB +=  '"' + str(verb[i])+ '"'
          if i != len(verb) - 1 and len(verb) != 1  :
              VERB += ' | '

      for i in range(0,len(det)):
          DET += '"'+ str(det[i])+ '"'
          if i != len(det) - 1 and len(det) != 1:
              DET += ' | '

      for i in range(0,len(adj)):
          ADJ += '"'+ str(adj[i])+ '"'
          if i != len(adj) - 1 and len(adj) != 1:
            ADJ += ' | '

      for i in range(0,len(adv)):
          ADV += '"'+ str(adv[i])+ '"'
          if i != len(adv) - 1 and len(adv) != 1:
            ADV += ' | '


      grammar = CFG.fromstring(f"""
                S ->  NP VP | VP NP
                NP -> DET N| ADJ N 
                VP -> V NP | V ADJ | V ADV
                V -> {VERB}
                N -> {NOUN}
                ADJ ->{ADJ}
                DET -> {DET}
                ADV -> {ADV}
                """)


    for i in range(50):
        # Swapping the `S` rule randomly
        if random.choice([True, False]):
            new_grammar = grammar.substitute(NP=grammar.productions()[0].rhs(), S=grammar.productions()[1].rhs())
        else:
            new_grammar = grammar.substitute(VP=grammar.productions()[0].rhs(), S=grammar.productions()[1].rhs())

        for sentence in generate(new_grammar, n=1):
            new_sent =  ' '.join(sentence)
            print(new_sent)
```

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3326, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)

  File "<ipython-input-26-81e9ddd4e9ec>", line 7, in <module>
    import substitute

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/substitute/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .substitute import *

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/substitute/substitute.py", line 126
    equals = lambda (a,b):a==b
                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Here I will randomly swap each Nonterminal and generate a sentence of the randomly swapped grammar structure. But how can I randomly swap those nonterminal like **S**, **NP**, **VP**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```py
import random
from nltk.grammar import CFG

grammar = CFG.fromstring(f"""
          S ->  NP VP | VP NP
          NP -> DET N| ADJ N 
          VP -> V NP | V ADJ | V ADV
          V -> {VERB}
          N -> {NOUN}
          ADJ ->{ADJ}
          DET -> {DET}
          ADV -> {ADV}
          """)

for i in range(50):
    # Swapping the `S` rule randomly
    if random.choice([True, False]):
        new_grammar = grammar.substitute(NP=grammar.productions()[0].rhs(), S=grammar.productions()[1].rhs())
    else:
        new_grammar = grammar.substitute(VP=grammar.productions()[0].rhs(), S=grammar.productions()[1].rhs())

    for sentence in generate(new_grammar, n=1):
        new_sent =  ' '.join(sentence)
        print(new_sent)
```

Here `substitute` method of the `CFG` class is used to create a new grammar with a nonterminal rule. `random.choice([True, False])` is used to give either `True` or `False` so that we can randomly select the swap we want to make.

#### Edit

Try this:

```py
for i in range(50):
    if random.choice([True, False]):
        new_grammar = CFG.fromstring(f"""
            S -> VP NP | NP VP
            NP -> DET N | ADJ N 
            VP -> V NP | V ADJ | V ADV
            V -> {VERB}
            N -> {NOUN}
            ADJ -> {ADJ}
            DET -> {DET}
            ADV -> {ADV}
        """)
    else:
        new_grammar = grammar

    for sentence in generate(new_grammar, n=1):
        new_sent = ' '.join(sentence)
        print(new_sent)
```

Comment: Hi, I'm getting a error **  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/substitute/substitute.py", line 126
    equals = lambda (a,b):a==b
                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax**

Comment: @Sunjaree Can you share the full traceback by editing the question? Also the error is not due to code in the answer.

Comment: I have shared the full code in the second block and  the full traceback

Comment: @Sunjaree I'd check it soon.

Comment: I think something is wrong with this substitute method

Comment: @Sunjaree try this `lambda a, b: a == b` instead of `lambda (a,b):a==b` remove the round brackets, as having `,` is considered as tuple and see if it helps.

Comment: but I don't have the access to grammar.substitute() method.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251889/discussion-between-sunderam-dubey-and-sunjaree).